# Zooming in without scaling graphics

Tags: opengl, scale, transformation

I'm learning Opengl for 2D, (in particular using the java slick2D library, but that might not be a factor for this question). I discovered I can change push a new transformation matrix, for instance to transform world coordinates into screen (view) coordinates.

I want to use this to zoom my view, increasing the distances between objects, but once this is done I want to paint images and shapes in screen coordinates, like a HUD. Basically, I want the coordinates to change, but the graphics to stay the same, so I can render custom images on each scale.

Can this be done with some clever transformation or some OpenGL option instead of manually calculating all coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

1. Clear color and depth buffers
2. Set projection/modelview matrices for zoomed 2D/3D rendering
3. Enable depth test
4. Render zoomed 2D/3D scene
5. Reset projection/modelview for 2D overlay
6. Disable depth test
7. Draw 2D overlay
8. Repeat

Comment: Actually that is not what I meant. There is no separate 2D and 3D, only a scale-invariant 2D scene. But I just figured out myself. Wrapping your head around a stack of transformations is definitely not trivial. I did vote for your answer since it is useful still, but I'll put the right one just in case. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out, you have to use two separate projection:

1.- Scale the world coordinates, so that the objects are drawn on the correct scene locations:

```
    g.pushTransform();

    // Always zoom in the center of the screen.
    g.translate(resolution.getX(), resolution.getY());
    g.scale(scale, scale);

    // Move the view
    g.translate(-view.getX(), -view.getY());
```

2.- Push a new matrix to draw the object, inverting the scale transformation so the object's graphics don't change with scale:

```
    g.pushTransform();

    // Center on the current object.
    g.translate(pos.x, pos.y);

    // Undo scaling of graphics!
    g.scale(1.0f/scale, 1.0f/scale);
```